# How to read in a char array by searching for a delimiter back to front

Tags: c++, search, delimiter

I'm curious is there is a quick way to search a line back to front for a particular delimiter.

example

```
C:\main\programs\Calvin and Hobbes
```

I want to store the `Calvin and Hobbes` part in a `char[]`. I'm thinking the easiest way, if possible, would be search the line back to front for a `\` and then capture everything found after that delimiter.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for not using std::string?

Comment: My university doesn't allow string, only char arrays

Comment: So you have an approach! What's stopping you from implementing that? You're not asking a question!

Answer (score 3):

Use `strrchr()` (reverse of `strchr()`).

Here's a [manpage](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strrchr/)

Answer (score 2):

If you have something like `const char *s`, you can find the last character using [`strrchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strrchr)

```
 auto* res = strrchr(s, '\\') + 1;
```

You can use `res` as a string, though it would share storage with `s`. You don't necessarily need to copy the result into a new string.  If the character is not present in `s` then you'll need to handle that case (check for null), in which case you wouldn't `+ 1` before checking.

```
auto* res = strrchr(s, '\\');
if (res) {
    ++res;
} else {
    std::cerr << "\\ character not present in s\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) then you can use [`std::basic_string::find_last_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of) like:

```
std::string path = "C:\\main\\programs\\Calvin and Hobbes";
std::size_t pos = path.find_last_of("\\");
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the character array to an `std::string`.  (Or read directly into a `std::string`).

Research the `std::string::find_last_of` method.  Also study the reverse iterators.

If you *must* use C-style character arrays, read up on the `str*()` functions.